# JAX-RS: Non-programmatical registration of a ClientRequestFilter

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs, resteasy

I want to use a ClientRequestFilter to modify outgoing REST requests of my application *without* changing the source code.

So far, I have only found ways to register my filter programmatically:

```
   Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(); 
   client.register(new MyClientRequestFilterImpl());
   webtarget =  client.target(uriBuilder);
```

Is it possible to use the web.xml or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such way but you can easily read a configuration file on your own. Assuming following file:

```
com.foo.bar.Filter1
com.foo.bar.Filter2
```

You can register the filters like this:

```
List<String> filters = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(new URI("/your/config/file")), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
for (String filter : filters) {
    client.register(Class.forName(filter));
}
```